# Unix pipes and positional arguments

Tags: bash, unix, pipe

I'm combining `sox` and `lame` to generate a new music file, but in order to do everything on one line using pipes, it seems necessary to 'mark' the output and input boundaries with a `-` character. I've inherited this code, so let me show.

```
sox $DIRNAME/$BASENAME -e signed-integer -r 8000 -c 2 -t wav - trim $POSITIONS | lame -v -V4 --resample 8 - $DIRNAME/${NOEXT}.mp3
```

The `-` between `wav` and `trim` is the output file, and the `-` between `--resample 8` and `$DIRNAME/${NOEXT}.mp3` is the input file.

I'm trying to find further information on this, like whether any character can be used, or if `-` is special in this way. What is this called, and what makes it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many Unix command-line utilities use "-" as a shorthand to mean "don't use a real file here, use stdin (or stdout) instead".  Sox is one of these programs:

This is from the [sox manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sox)

> SoX can be used in simple pipeline operations by using the special
>   filename '-' which, if used in place of an input filename, will cause
>   SoX will read audio data from 'standard input' (stdin), and which, if
>   used in place of the output filename, will cause SoX will send audio
>   data to 'standard output' (stdout). Note that when using this option,
>   the file-type (see -t below) must also be given.

Answer (score 2):

By convention, unix and friends use `-` to represent stdin and stdout.

It's not 100% universal, but it's a pretty widely used.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, it's the same thing as

```
/dev/stdin
```

Try to replace your `-` with it, you will see.

Answer (score 2):

"-" is often use as a convention instead of a file name to say "use the standard input (instead or reading for the file) or standard output (instead of writing to the file)". This is not a feature of the command shell (i.e. bash), so in that sense, it is not a special character. It is a feature of some commands (like in your case "sox" and "lame") and is very useful to chain these commands through pipes.